# PayFlow (Direct) setting orders to On Hold

Tags: payment-gateway, magento-1.4

We've been using PayFlow Pro Direct Payments on our 1.4.0.1 site for several years. All of a sudden we've been getting all orders placed through there with a status of "On Hold" and this message on the order:
Payflow PNREF: #999999999999. Amount of $99.99 pending approval on gateway.

This is how I have it setup:

[image]

What is wrong?

Note, please don't tell me to upgrade, this install was done by contractors that severely customized it by not following standard principles, mainly by editing core source, and so we will not be able to upgrade. This installation is also tightly coupled with an ExpressionEngine CMS and later versions of Magento do not work well with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had trouble with Payflow Pro setting orders on hold, it was due to advanced fraud filtering settings. It doesn't look like this is your problem, but have you tried turning those off?

Comment: Where do I turn them off?

Comment: In your PayPal Manager dashboard. Service Settings > Fraud Protection > Live Setup. You should also check and see what the order details look like while you're in the PayPal Manager dashboard using "Search Transactions."

Comment: I don't have access to that, our accounting dept. handles the PayPal acct. I will contact them.

Comment: Good plan. You will need access to that information, or someone who can help you troubleshoot that has access to that information. PayPal Support can be a pretty good resource as well, as they have access to their own logs.

Comment: Believe it or not, it had to do with a modification I made to NVP.php to "fake" IPNs for our development site. The code got pushed to production.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!